# Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a problem with this part of the code. It is for storing an image file on the server. It was working well, but it stopped and no longer works now on the real phone, but it works on the emulator without problems.
On the real phone the error appears: Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
What's the solution ? Note that I use 000webhost as a temporary server for testing

img Size about : 4MB
Https protocol, emulator v is 30 and device v is 33

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .callTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
        val mediaType = "text/plain".toMediaType()
        println( File(filePath).length())
        val body = MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("image","",
                File(filePath).asRequestBody("application/octet-stream".toMediaType()))
            .build()
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("#####")
            .post(body)
            .build()
            try {
                val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val responseBody = response.body
                    if (responseBody != null) {
                        val responseString = responseBody.string()
                        println("Response: $responseString")
                    }
                } else {
                    println("Request failed: ${response.code}")
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("Error: $e")
            }
```

I am trying to save an image on the server for later use, but I get this error

Comment: `.url("#####")` Please show protocol. Tell Android versions of emulator and device.

Comment: `val mediaType = "text/plain".toMediaType()` ???

Comment: Try File(filePath).exists() and File(filePath).canRead() before you try to upload.

Comment: Https protocol, emulator v is 30 and device v is 33